# Automated Deployment, Global.asax: Could not load type Namespace.Global

Tags: c#, web-services, deployment, compilation, global-asax

This is my first StackOverflow post.  Thanks in advance!  I've found a lot of answers here, but can't find anything about my current issue anywhere on the web.  =(

I have a C# Service I've tested and deployed using the WCFRestWebService template found online in Visual Studio 2010 Express.  When I 'Publish' the project to my web server, the service functions as desired.  The service requires three files to function online, that is my web.config, global.asax, and bin/WCFRestWebService1.dll.

So then I thought, why can't I write a program to generate these three files and FTP those files to my web server for me.  So I wrote this:

```
namespace Edifice
{
    //code behind for ASP.Net page
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    { 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //the first Write() method returns an array of strings 
            //containing .cs files for the project, in this particular 
            //case, 2 strings, one containing the service.cs and one 
            //containing global.asax.cs
            string[] parameters = eConfig.midTier.Write(eConfig);
            string webConfig = eConfig.midTier.WriteWebConfig(eConfig);
            string globalAsax = eConfig.midTier.WriteGlobalAsax(eConfig);
            Assembly assembly = ECompiler.BuildAssembly(eConfig.className, parameters);
            EFTP.Upload(assembly, webConfig, globalAsax, eConfig);
        }
    }
    public static class EFTP
    {
        //for this sample, FTP merely saves the file to the current file system for testing
        public static void Upload(Assembly sourceFile, string webConfig, string globalAsax, EConfiguration eConfig)
        {
            string filepath = "C:\\EdificeTest\\dlls\\";
            using (Stream oStream = new FileStream(filepath + "bin\\" + "WCFRESTService2.dll", FileMode.Create))
            {
                StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(oStream);
                sWriter.Write(sourceFile);
                sWriter.Close();
            }
            using (Stream oStream = new FileStream(filepath + "Web.config", FileMode.Create))
            {
                StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(oStream);
                sWriter.Write(webConfig);
                sWriter.Close();
            }
            using (Stream oStream = new FileStream(filepath + "Global.asax", FileMode.Create))
            {
                StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(oStream);
                sWriter.Write(globalAsax);
                sWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    public static class ECompiler
    {
        public static Assembly BuildAssembly(string assemblyName, string[] sources)
        {
            List<string> WCFRestServiceAssemblies = new List<string>();
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Configuration.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.EnterpriseServices.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Runtime.Serialization.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.ServiceModel.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.ServiceModel.Web.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Web.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Web.DynamicData.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Web.Entity.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Web.Extensions.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Web.Services.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
            WCFRestServiceAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");

            Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<String, String> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
            ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters(WCFRestServiceAssemblies.ToArray());
            compilerparams.OutputAssembly = assemblyName + ".dll";
            compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
            compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = true;
            CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(compilerparams, sources);

            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                           error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
                }
                throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return results.CompiledAssembly;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So then, the problem is that even though the exact same code can be pasted into the Visual Studio project and I can compile and publish that service from Visual Studio (AND it WORKS!), when I try to use the same files generated by these methods, I get an error when I try to invoke the service:

> [HttpException]: Could not load type 'EdificeTest.Global'.
>   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String
>   baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly
>   assembly)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary
>   parseData)

'EdificeTest' is the namespace for the web service, and is being referenced by the Global.asax file.  From my analysis, it appears that for a 'Published' service, the Global.asax.cs file is compiled and added to the assembly, and the Global.asax file references its 'codebehind' file in the assembly.  This seems to work when visual studio is in charge of packaging the project, however I must be missing a step in my automated deployment because it can't find the type for the 'Inherits=' attribute in Global.asax and it throws the error.

Please help?

Comment: Why is it that you're looking to reinvent deployment when MS Web Deployment works and can be easily automated through MSBuild, PowerShell, etc?

Comment: It appears that if I don't compile the Global.asax.cs, and instead change the Global.asax source to use CodeFile="" instead of Codebehind="", then I can defer the compilation of the Global.asax.cs until the service is executed.  So I would have four files uploaded instead of three.  Seems silly that it would be so difficult to just compile and link the Global.asax.cs file, however, it appears that this fix actually addresses the issue.  I'm still curious if I could pre-compile the global class and use codebehind=""?

Comment: I had not considered MSBuild, Powershell, etc mostly out of ignorance.  I will read up on these options and see how they would apply to this case.  In my haste, I elected to whip together this custom code instead of learning something new.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem.
If you don't want your global codebehind class to be in assembly, you can use inline code in global.asax, instead of inheritting/codebehind:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script RunAt="server">
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Drag and `drop your Global.asax.cs` file into `App_Code folder`.
It will fixed all your boring problems related to Global.asax.cs file.

Cheers,
Jignesh Jinjariya